# Windows Aero Glass background is broken after hibernate. How can I solve this?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, aero-glass

I am developing a program in C# .net 3.5 wpf. It has to work on windows xp, windows vista and windows 7. On the newer operation systems I wantet to create the background in Aero Glass. So this is only a special design. After hibernate, after suspending or after changing windows Desings to a basic design and back to aero all the added glass is displayed completely black.

I display Glass via the GlassHelper Class (can be found with Google).

Actually I see 3 ways to solve this problem. The first is, yea to solve it. But i read somwhere, that this is a bug in the Windows Managed Code so I have no option to sovle it. Correct me, if I am wrong.

So I had the idea to close the window everytime, it is minimized and to rebuild completely, when it s used next time.

That works quite well. After hibernate the window is still displayed black, but i do not have to quit the application, i can still minimize it and maximize again.

Now I see to ways:

1) I close the window everytime, the computer suspends, hibernates or changes the design. And I open it the window again, when it is save. But how can I handle this?

2) I accept, that the window will be displayed in black, until someone minimizes it. (Not my favourite) But then I get a new Problem: The Button in The Taskbar. (Not the Tray Icon). I need it to be displayed permanently. On winxp i need it to open the window, when minimized. And especially on win7 I need it because I want to use some of the new Advantages of the Superbar! (the preview by hoovering will not be the window, it will be a static picture.)

Thank you everyone, for helping me!

Comment: Is this a problem with other programs on your development system, or just the program you're building?

Comment: It is just the programm, that I am building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thank you everyone! But I think I found my own solution!

I handle the Messages: WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED (0x031E) & WM_THEMECHANGED (0x031A)

and on catching one of those messages I simply assign the glass again or a new background depending on DwmIsCompositionEnabled().

Actually I have something similar to the following:

```
const int WM_THEMECHANGED = 0x031A;
const int WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED = 0x031E;

private static void ApplyTheme(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    if (DwmIsCompositionEnabled())
    {
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd).CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        MARGINS margins = new MARGINS(new Thickness(-1));
        DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, ref margins);
    }
    else
    {
        HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd).CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrush.Color;
    }
}

private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == WM_THEMECHANGED)
    {
        ApplyTheme(hwnd);
    }
    if (msg == WM_DWMCOMPOSITIONCHANGED)
    {
        ApplyTheme(hwnd);
    }
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

I get the hwnd.

I hook it.

```
HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd).AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
```

I make the WPF Window Background transparent, because later, in the WndProc function I will only be able to access my hwnd Background (Win32).

```
window.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
```

And now I only have to assign the style for the first time:

```
ApplyTheme(hwnd);
```

Thats it! Works perfectly for me (Win 64 Home Premium) after I disable or enable aero, switch between different aero or non-aero styles or hibernate, so it is exactly, what I was looking for. Thank you, for your great ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Try to handle WM_NCCALCSIZE message and reduce client area (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS.rgrc0) by one pixel. I'm serious. I found this solution is used in Google Chrome and it works fine for me too.

Comment: Ok, I will although try this sollution... Thank you, bit since it is half past midnight I will do this tomorrow!

Comment: Look at this http://src.chromium.org/svn/branches/329/src/views/window/window_win.cc and search for "gfx::Insets WindowWin::GetClientAreaInsets"

Comment: Hey, I tried yours so far, because it lokked a little smarter but I was not able to solve my problem. My Program has no longer a black backgound, but freezes on non aero theme and on a newer theme again it is completely transparent, i only can see the border.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [WPF Shell Integration Library](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell).
I can rememver there were similar problems with that library due to a bug in the Desktop Window Manager in windows 7. The library has its source available so you can take a look how they handle it.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at it!

Comment: Ok. The test app with the shell gets black with an older windows theme. But the difference is, that it completele restores its old look, when you switch back to aero. Think, that this would be a good deal. I will try to use that in my own application. Thanks!